# Displaying Default Image on Custom Control help? MSDN Tutorial

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, blend

I'm doing a tutorial on MSDN on how to create a Custom Control

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295235(v=expression.30).aspx

I'm having trouble trying to display a default image on my button.

Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ControlTest
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();


    }

}
[Description("Represents a custom button control that responds to a Click event. Displays an image using a custom Source property if the Source property is bound to an Image in the template.")]
public class ImageButton : Button 
{ 
    [Description("The image displayed in the button if there is an Image control in the template whose Source property is template-bound to the ImageButton Source property."), Category("Common Properties")] 
    public ImageSource Source 
    { 
        get { return base.GetValue(SourceProperty) as ImageSource; } 
        set { base.SetValue(SourceProperty, value); } 
    } 
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton)); 

    // Constructor:  
    public ImageButton()  
    {  
    if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))  
    {  
        this.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/Image.png", UriKind.Relative));  
        }  
    }  


}
```

}

Thanks for your help! =)

Comment: Do you have a images/Image.png file?

Comment: Yes I do. I double checked. Do you think it could possibly just be a bug on Blend 4?

Comment: I would put a try catch in the constructor and be sure it is getting an image.  Try @"images/Image.png".

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a `DependencyProperty` you can specify a default value for it, like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Source", typeof (ImageSource), typeof (ImageButton), new PropertyMetadata("images/Image.png"));
```

The last argument of `DependencyProperty.Register` is a `PropertyMetadata` you can use to specify a default `ImageSource`.
I hope this helps.